# How to deny the move to the next WizardPage in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

How to deny the move to the next WizardPage in C#.net.

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit more: What wizard? If you are implementing your own, what framework are you using? (Short) example code always makes questions easier to understand.

Comment: What control are you talking about exactly

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590149/how-to-deny-the-move-to-the-next-wizardpage-in-c-net-i-am-using-wizard-control-i

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the "next" button until the wizard page has been completed properly.