# How to deny the move to the next WizardPage in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Wizard control in VS 2008. I searched the next button coding from net.vI want that if user id and password not match then wizard page should not move to the next step.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? 
As far as I know, there is no 'Wizard control' in .NET (or maybe in ASP.NET?)

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the OnNextButtonClick event and do your valiadation. If your validation fail set the cancel property of the WizardNavigationEventArgs to true.

```
protected void ClientWizard_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
  if(password dont match ....)
  e.Cancel = true;
}
```